# How to add the text at the end of the text inside textbox

Tags: javascript

I got a textbox with name=moderator[custom] and id=moderator-custom, I already have a addon that adds text inside a textbox using custom generators based on name=, it adds text, but the textbox already got random text everytime and I just want to add a text at the end of all that info.

The custom generator that I use to insert the text:

```
var text1 = faker.random.arrayElement([
           'hello!',
     ]);
return text1;
```

How should it look to place the "Hello!" at the end of all te info, keeping the text there too.

Comment: Define hello as a constant and add it to the end of your textarea value like doc.getEleById('moderator-costume').innerHTML = 'xxxxxx' + 'hello!';

Comment: Can you modify the code I pasted please?

Answer (score 1):

there are three steps involved in doing what you want.

1. Retrieve the existing value in the control
2. Append the new value to the retrieved value
3. Re-assign it to the control.

   ```
   var item = document.getElementById(moderator-custom");
   var text1 = faker.random.arrayElement([
      'hello!',
   ]);
   item.value += text1.value;
   ```

Comment: Couldn't be just done by the part of "return text1;"? Kinda noob in this, sorry :/

Comment: what are you returning it TO?  In my example above, if you had a function that returns text1 (and note: your code doesn't say it's in a function), then you can replace 'append this data' with your function call.  I'm editing the above code to include your value getter.

Comment: there's no "return" in that

Comment: you've got a line break you need to get rid of.  moderator-custom should be on one line.  I fixed it in my example (i run a high zoom level and it word-wrapped it)